# Vue: Best approach to access possible existing nested properties in error object

Tags: javascript, forms, vue.js, vuejs3, yup

I'm looking for a good and reusable approach to access possible existing nested properties (nested object and array of objects) inside an error object without typeErrors.

I have a `createCompany` form/page with the following data

```
data() {
    return {
        company: {
            same_billing_address: true,
            physical_address: {},
            billing_address: {},
            contacts: [
                {
                    function: '',
                    first_name: '',
                    last_name: '',
                    phone: '',
                    gender: 'female',
                    email: '',
                    language: 'nl',
                    date_of_birth: '',
                },
            ],
        },
        validationErrors: {},
    }
}
```

The form itself looks like this

```
<form @submit.prevent="createCompany" @keydown.enter="$event.preventDefault()" class="divide-y">
    <fieldset class="pb-6">
        <header>
            <h3 class="mb-3 text-lg leading-6 font-medium text-gray-900">{{ $tc('general', 1) }}</h3>
        </header>

        <div class="grid grid-cols-12 gap-x-6 gap-y-3">
            <div class="col-span-12">
                <InputWithButton :label="$tc('enterprise_number', 1)" buttonLabel="Get enterprise data" :onClick="getEnterpriseData" type="text" id="enterprise_number" v-model="company.enterprise_number" :error="validationErrors.enterprise_number" />
            </div>
            <div class="col-span-6">
                <Input :label="$tc('business_name', 1)" type="text" id="companyName" v-model="company.business_name" :error="validationErrors.business_name" />
            </div>
            <div class="col-span-6">
                <Input :label="$tc('legal_entity_type', 1)" type="text" id="companyType" v-model="company.legal_entity_type" :error="validationErrors.legal_entity_type" />
            </div>
            <div class="col-span-3">
                <Input :label="$tc('phone', 1)" type="text" id="phone" v-model="company.phone" :error="validationErrors.phone" />
            </div>
            <div class="col-span-6">
                <Input :label="$tc('email_address', 1)" type="text" id="email" v-model="company.email" :error="validationErrors.email" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </fieldset>

    <fieldset class="py-6">
        <header>
            <h3 class="mb-3 text-lg leading-6 font-medium text-gray-900">{{ $tc('physical_address', 1) }}</h3>
        </header>

        <div class="grid grid-cols-12 gap-x-6 gap-y-3">
            <div class="col-span-8">
                <Input :label="$tc('street', 1)" type="text" id="street" v-model="company.physical_address.street" :error="validationErrors.physical_address.street" />
            </div>
            <div class="col-span-2">
                <Input :label="$tc('number', 1)" type="text" id="number" v-model="company.physical_address.number" :error="validationErrors.physical_address.number" />
            </div>
            <div class="col-span-2">
                <Input :label="$tc('addition', 1)" optional type="text" id="addition" v-model="company.physical_address.addition" :error="validationErrors.physical_address.addition" />
            </div>
            <div class="col-span-8">
                <SelectWithSearch :label="$tc('city', 1)" id="billing_address_postal_code_id" v-model="company.physical_address.postal_code_id" :options="cityOptions" displayProperty="display_name" valueProperty="id" :minLengthForDropdown="3" :error="validationErrors.physical_address.zip_city" />
            </div>
            <div class="col-span-4">
                <Input :label="$tc('country', 1)" type="text" id="country" v-model="company.physical_address.country" :error="validationErrors.physical_address.country" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </fieldset>

    <fieldset class="py-6">
        <header>
            <h3 class="mb-3 text-lg leading-6 font-medium text-gray-900">{{ $tc('billing_address', 1) }}</h3>
        </header>

        <div class="grid grid-cols-12 gap-x-6 gap-y-3">
            <div class="col-span-12">
                <Checkbox :label="$tc('billing_same_as_physical', 1)" v-model="company.same_billing_address" :error="validationErrors.same_billing_address" />
            </div>

            <template v-if="!company.same_billing_address">
                <div class="col-span-8">
                    <Input :label="$tc('street', 1)" type="text" id="street" v-model="company.billing_address.street" :error="validationErrors.billing_address.street" />
                </div>
                <div class="col-span-2">
                    <Input :label="$tc('number', 1)" type="text" id="number" v-model="company.billing_address.number" :error="validationErrors.billing_address.number" />
                </div>
                <div class="col-span-2">
                    <Input :label="$tc('addition', 1)" type="text" id="addition" v-model="company.billing_address.addition" :error="validationErrors.billing_address.addition" />
                </div>
                <div class="col-span-8">
                    <SelectWithSearch :label="$tc('city', 1)" id="billing_address_postal_code_id" v-model="company.billing_address.postal_code_id" :options="cityOptions" displayProperty="display_name" valueProperty="id" :minLengthForDropdown="3" :error="validationErrors.billing_address.zip_city" />
                </div>
                <div class="col-span-4">
                    <Input :label="$tc('country', 1)" type="text" id="country" v-model="company.billing_address.country" :error="validationErrors.billing_address.country" />
                </div>
            </template>
        </div>
    </fieldset>

    <fieldset class="py-6">
        <div class="flex justify-between mb-3">
            <header>
                <h3 class="text-lg leading-6 font-medium text-gray-900">{{ $tc('contact', company.contacts.length) }}</h3>
            </header>
            <button type="button" class="text-sm leading-6 font-medium text-blue-500 flex items-center" @click="addContact">{{ $tc('add', 1) }} {{ $tc('contact', 1).toLowerCase() }}</button>
        </div>

        <section class="space-y-6">
            <div v-for="(contact, contactIdx) in company.contacts" :key="contactIdx">
                <h4 v-show="company.contacts.length > 1" class="mb-3 text-sm leading-6 font-medium text-gray-500">
                    {{ $tc('contact', 1) }} {{ contactIdx + 1 }} <span @click="deleteContact(contactIdx)" class="text-blue-500 cursor-pointer select-none">({{ $tc('delete', 1) }})</span>
                </h4>

                <div class="grid grid-cols-12 gap-x-6 gap-y-3">
                    <div class="col-span-12">
                        <RadioButtonGroup :label="$tc('gender', 1)" :options="genderOptions" v-model="contact.gender" :error="contacts[contactIdx].gender" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-span-6">
                        <Input :label="$tc('first_name', 1)" type="text" id="first_name" v-model="contact.first_name" :error="contacts[contactIdx].first_name" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-span-6">
                        <Input :label="$tc('last_name', 1)" type="text" id="last_name" v-model="contact.last_name" :error="contacts[contactIdx].last_name" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-span-3">
                        <Input :label="$tc('phone', 1)" type="text" id="phone" v-model="contact.phone" :error="contacts[contactIdx].phone" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-span-6">
                        <Input :label="$tc('email_address', 1)" type="text" id="email" v-model="contact.email" :error="contacts[contactIdx].email" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-span-3">
                        <Input :label="$tc('date_of_birth', 1)" type="date" id="date_of_birth" v-model="contact.date_of_birth" :error="contacts[contactIdx].date_of_birth" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-span-9">
                        <Input :label="$tc('function', 1)" type="text" id="function" v-model="contact.function" :error="contacts[contactIdx].function" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-span-3">
                        <Select :label="$tc('language', 1)" id="languageOfContact" :options="languageOptions" displayProperty="display_name" valueProperty="name" v-model="contact.language" :error="contacts[contactIdx].language" />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
    </fieldset>

    <fieldset class="pt-6">
        <SubmitButton :label="$tc('create_company', 1)" submittingLabel="Creating company..." />
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

Before the data is send to the backend it is validated

```
async createCompany() {
    try {
        await CreateCompanyValidationSchema.validate(this.company, { abortEarly: false });
        console.log('all good');
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err.inner);
        err.inner.forEach((error) => {
            this.validationErrors = { ...this.validationErrors, [error.path]: error.message };
        });
    }
}
```

I'm using `Yup` to validate the form. The schema looks like this

```
export const CreateCompanyValidationSchema = yup.object().shape({
    enterprise_number: yup.string(),
    business_name: yup.string(),
    legal_entity_type: yup.string(),
    phone: yup.string().required(),
    email: yup.string().required().email(),
    language: yup.string().required(),
    first_name: yup.string(),
    last_name: yup.string(),
    date_of_birth: yup.date(),
    physical_address: yup.object({
        street: yup.string().required(),
        number: yup.string().required(),
        addition: yup.string(),
        zip_city: yup.string().required(),
        country: yup.string().required(),
    }),
    same_billing_address: yup.boolean(),
    billing_address: yup.object().when('same_billing_address', {
        is: false,
        then: yup.object({
            street: yup.string().required(),
            number: yup.string().required(),
            addition: yup.string(),
            zip_city: yup.string().required(),
            country: yup.string().required(),
        }),
    }),
    contacts: yup.array().of(
        yup.object().shape({
            gender: yup.string().required().oneOf(['male', 'female', 'other']),
            first_name: yup.string().required(),
            last_name: yup.string().required(),
            phone: yup.string().required(),
            email: yup.string().required().email(),
            date_of_birth: yup.date().required(),
            function: yup.string().required(),
            language: yup.string().required().oneOf(['nl', 'fr', 'en']),
        })
    ),
});
```

The `validationErrors` data object has a nested object structure (`physical_address` and `billing_address`) and a nested array of objects (`contacts`). The `validationErrors` object is empty in the beginning. If the nested address fields or the contacts are valid, the validationErrors object will not have any nested properties. But in the form I'm accessing child properties like `validationErrors.contacts[contactIdx].phone` or `validationErrors.billing_address.street`. This causes errors because these properties do not exist. What is the best approach to counter this? I'm looking for a reusable solution for multiple forms with this structure.

Comment: It's Vue 2 app, isn't it? You could use `?.` optional navigation operator, but it won't work inside Vue 2 templates. Probably instead of accessing validationErrors directly use a method that wraps around Lodash `get` or similar safe navigation utility

Comment: It's a vue 3 app and we would like to avoid using Lodash. Using `?.` is an option for `validationErrors.billing_address.street` but what about the contacts? I don't think this is possible `validationErrors.contacts?[contactIdx].phone`

Comment: Lodash is the most popular one. There should be tiny alternatives.

Comment: I will check the lodash `get` function and see to write a native reusable function

Comment: The implementation is really simple and takes several lines if the performance is not in priority.

Answer (score 2):

One option is to use short-circuiting to safely access nested properties, only if they exist.

```
if ( validationErrors && validationErrors.billing_address ) {
    console.log(validationErrors.billing_address.street)
}
```

The if-statement is only true if `validationErrors.billing_address` is defined, but it won't throw an error if `validationErrors` is undefined.

If you think that this pattern is too ugly and repetitive, you might be interested in using a library to help you access nested properties.
https://lodash.com/docs/#get

Answer (score 2):

In Vue 3, optional chaining (safe navigation) operator can be used directly in templates to access non-existent keys:

```
:error="contacts?.[contactIdx]?.first_name"
```

In Vue 2, this requires to move this code to a method and likely specify a path to nested property with strings, for example with Lodash `get` or similar helper function, which also allows to specify default value for non-existent keys.